# Precise definitions of map, shuffle, merge and reduce times in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

In Hadoop the following metrics are supplied after a job execution:

- map time
- reduce time
- shuffle time
- merge time

I can't find an exact definition of these times as all sources remain unclear on how these times are exactly calculated. This is how I see it:

- Map time is the time to read **input** and apply map function and **sort the data**
- Reduce time is the time to apply reduce function and write **output**
- Shuffle time is the time to **merge** the map sorted data an transfer is to the reducers
- Merge time is the time to merge the map outputs **at the reduce side only**

I am uncertain about the things in bold. Is my analysis correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I decided to look into the Hadoop code to gain more insight. The image below explains my findings.
[image: Map reduce overview]

I discovered that:

- Map time is the time taken by the map tasks. Map task are responsible for reading input, applying the map function, sorting the data and merging the data.
- Shuffle time is the time to copy the map output data to a reduce task, this is part of a reduce task.
- Merge time is the time to merge the map outputs at the reduce side, this is part of a reduce task.
- Reduce time is the time to apply the reduce function and write the output.

These findings are supported by the following code code:

In the [Shuffle](http://search-hadoop.com/c/MapReduce:hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/task/reduce/Shuffle.java||copyPhase.complete) class, which is used by a [ReduceTask](http://search-hadoop.com/c/MapReduce:hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/ReduceTask.java||run+ReduceTask), we see that the "copy" phase is followed by a "sort" phase.

```
copyPhase.complete(); // copy is already complete
taskStatus.setPhase(TaskStatus.Phase.SORT);
reduceTask.statusUpdate(umbilical);

// Finish the on-going merges...
RawKeyValueIterator kvIter = null;
try {
  kvIter = merger.close();
} catch (Throwable e) {
  throw new ShuffleError("Error while doing final merge " , e);
}
```

In the [TaskStatus](http://search-hadoop.com/c/MapReduce:hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskStatus.java||TaskStatus.Phase+oldPhase+%253D+getPhase) class we see that the shuffletime is the time BEFORE the sort phase and the sort time is the time between the shuffle and reduce phases.

```
public void setPhase(Phase phase){
  TaskStatus.Phase oldPhase = getPhase();
  if (oldPhase != phase){
    // sort phase started
    if (phase == TaskStatus.Phase.SORT){
      if (oldPhase == TaskStatus.Phase.MAP) {
        setMapFinishTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
      }
      else {
        setShuffleFinishTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
      }
    }else if (phase == TaskStatus.Phase.REDUCE){
      setSortFinishTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    this.phase = phase;
  }
  ...
```

In the [JobInfo](http://search-hadoop.com/c/MapReduce:hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/v2/hs/webapp/dao/JobInfo.java||+avgMergeTime) class we see that shuffle time corresponds to the copying, and that merge time is the "sort" time we mentioned above.

```
switch (task.getType()) {
    case MAP:
      successfulMapAttempts += successful;
      failedMapAttempts += failed;
      killedMapAttempts += killed;
      if (attempt.getState() == TaskAttemptState.SUCCEEDED) {
        numMaps++;
        avgMapTime += (attempt.getFinishTime() - attempt.getLaunchTime());
      }
      break;
    case REDUCE:
      successfulReduceAttempts += successful;
      failedReduceAttempts += failed;
      killedReduceAttempts += killed;
      if (attempt.getState() == TaskAttemptState.SUCCEEDED) {
        numReduces++;
        avgShuffleTime += (attempt.getShuffleFinishTime() - attempt
            .getLaunchTime());
        avgMergeTime += attempt.getSortFinishTime()
            - attempt.getShuffleFinishTime();
        avgReduceTime += (attempt.getFinishTime() - attempt
            .getSortFinishTime());
      }
}
```

More information on how the reduce and map task work may be derived from the classes [MapTask](http://search-hadoop.com/c/MapReduce:hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/MapTask.java||run+MapTask) and [ReduceTask](http://search-hadoop.com/c/MapReduce:hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/ReduceTask.java||run+ReduceTask), respectively.

Finally, I would like to note that the source code I refer to in the links mostly corresponds to the Hadoop 2.7.1 code.